# Hatcher deduce ring structure on $H^\ast(\mathbb{R}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-topology

So in Hatcher they deduce the ring structure of $H^\ast (\mathbb{R}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z})$ by looking at the map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_2$, which induces maps on $H^\ast(\mathbb{R}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}_2)$. What I don't understand is how they deduce the injectivity. It's probably something stupidly simple, but my brain isn't really working. I'd appreciate any help I can get.

[image]

Comment: If you look at the positive dimensional cohomology of the top row you get either zero (in which case injectivity is trivial), or $\mathbb Z/2$ in which case you get an isomorphism (the vertical maps in the diagram are the projection $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2$).

Comment: That was dumb of me.I thought the sequences above were on the cohomology level rather than the cochain level which was what was giving me issues. Thanks.